# Drawing with interior angle and distance

Tags: qgis, azimuth

In QGIS Azimuth and distance plugin draws with azimuth angle and distance. I want to draw with interior angle between consecutive lines. For the starting point and base station(reference point to plot 1st point) I have azimuth angles. Any plugin to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Would the `View/Toolbars/Advanced Digitizing Toolbar` work for you with the relative angle modes?

Documentation at https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#the-advanced-digitizing-panel

[image]